# Opening the same session in Paramiko

Tags: python-3.x, network-programming, session-cookies, paramiko

```
self.conn_ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
self.conn_ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
self.conn_ssh.connect(
        hostname=self.hostname,
        port=22,
        username=self.username,
        password=self.password,
    )
self.ssh_channel = self.conn_ssh.invoke_shell()
```

I am trying to run this program once and open the paramiko session and channel
After that when I try to run again I need to check if the channel or session exists use that 
and so is the requirement, that I need to use the same session handler 
Thank you in advance